# #import mutliple non-framework class header files in xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, import, xcode5, header-files

I have many header files `D1TVC to D12TVC` I need to import into `DisciplineTableViewController`how can I do this in one line of code in the `DisciplineTableViewController`similar to the angled framework brackets?

Edit: Forgot the screenshot!

[image: header files]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create other header file that includes 12 D#TVC.h, You can look in that header files that is what they have.

```
  //DTVC.h
  #import "D1TVC.h"
  #import "D2TVC.h"
  #import "D3TVC.h"
  #import "D4TVC.h"
  #import "D5TVC.h"
  #import "D6TVC.h"
  #import "D7TVC.h"
  #import "D8TVC.h"
  #import "D9TVC.h"
  #import "D10TVC.h"
  #import "D11TVC.h"
  #import "D12TVC.h"
```